# Can I close this exterior wall opening or is it required? Seems like energy leak

Tags: walls

I’m gutting a 1977 A frame house. The exterior walls have an open vent to the soffit at the top. I have had critter issues in the past and would like seal the wall.

Can I close this opening or is it required?

[image]

Comment: Seems unusual to have those openings.  Most external sheeting goes right to the top of the wall.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 8):

I've never seen an opening like that and know of no codes that mandate it. My guess is that they cut the plywood wrong and used it anyway, then added scrap 2x4s for a nailer, laid them flat so insulation could fit in. I would close it up.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I am going to close up the holes.